# Windows Store Package and Precompiled Headers

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-store, precompiled-headers

Using Visual Studio 17, I have created a project that doesn't use precompiled headers. The project compiles and executes successfully, But when I try to create a store app package the build process fails with the message:

```
"unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. 
Did you forget to add #include stdafx.h to your source?"
```

No, I didn't forget to add it. I don't use precompiled headers, but the create package process refuses to acknowledge that.

Can anyone provide a workaround for this?

Comment: The compiler obviously thinks you are using precompiled headers. Check its settings, and make sure you and it are in agreement.

Comment: all components are set to not use precompiled headers. the project compiles and executes fine. it's when i try to package it for the store that the problem occurs.  there is no setting within the packager regarding precompiled headers, as far as i can see.

Comment: ok, i just had to make sure i was setting "no precompiled headers" for all configurations and all platforms, because the packager was compiling for platforms i hadn't been using.